# Unregistering character device

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

beginners Q: I tried to get device numbers using:

```
 alloc_chrdev_region(&device, 0, 1, "chardev");
```

and then in the stop module for the driver, unregistered it using

```
 unregister_chrdev_region(MAJOR(device),1);
```

After the 'alloc' function call, the device name is visible in /proc/device but after calling the 'unregister' function as above the device is still visible in /proc/devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some combinations got it. Need to use:

```
 unregister_chrdev_region(device,1);
```

That is, the whole device number should be used instead of just the 'major' number.